# Show $G\cong \ker(f) \times \mathbb{Z}$ for abelian $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

First of all, I am aware of the First Isomorphism Theorem but I am not sure how to use it/if it is useful here

$G$ is an abelian group and $f:G\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is a surjective group homomorphism. I need to show $G\cong \ker(f) \times \mathbb{Z}$. I need to do so by the following: choose some $s\in G$ with $f(s)=1\in\mathbb{Z}$, and use $s$ to find a homomorphism from $G$ to $\ker(f)\times\mathbb{Z}$ and show this is bijective.

I am not really sure how $s$ would help me find this 'second' homomorphism so I haven't really made any progress. My only attempt has been to do with that homomorphisms preserve the identity, but since $1$ is not the identity of $\mathbb{Z}$ I don't think is the right way to think about the problem. I am also not sure how $G$ being abelian helps.

Comment: This is what I thought, but no the question definitely says $f(s)=1$

Answer (score 2):

Let for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, $A_m:=\{g\in G:f(g)=m\}$. Since $f$ is a subjective homomorphism, $A_m$ is non-empty for every $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $s\in G$ be such that $f(s)=1$. Such $s$ exists due to subjectivity of $f$. Then by properties of homomorphis, $f(ms)=m$ $\forall$ $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Define the following map, $\varphi: G\longrightarrow \mathrm{ker}(f)\times \mathbb{Z}$ by the following rule,
$$\varphi(g):= (g-f(g)s,f(g))\quad (\forall g\in G)$$
It's easy to verify that $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism. Then we show that $\varphi$ is also a bijection in order to establish isomorphism.

$$\varphi(g_1)=\varphi(g_2)\implies g_1-f(g_1)s = g_2-f(g_2)s\implies g_1=g_2$$ 
Hence $\varphi$ is injective.

Let $(k,m)$ be in $\mathrm{ker}(f)\times\mathbb{Z}$. We have to choose a $g$ in $A_m$ such that $k=g-f(g)s=g-ms$. Obviously we see that $g=k+ms$ works. Then $\varphi$ is subjective also. Hence $\varphi$ is bijective or $G\cong \mathrm{ker}(f)\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How is it true that $f(ms)=m$?

Comment: Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $$f(ms)=f(s+s\ldots+s)=f(s)+f(s)+\ldots+f(s)=1+1+\ldots+1=m$$ There are $m$ summands within the brackets.

Comment: In saying $f(m\cdot s)=f(s+s+...+s)$ are we not just assuming that the operation $\cdot$ in $G$ is multiplication? In which case I don't see how $f(s+s+...+s)=f(s)+f(s)+...+f(s)$ since it is true that $f(a\cdot b)=f(a)+f(b)$ for $f$, but not true that $f(a + b)=f(a)+f(b)$

Comment: I have assumed additive group structure. $m$ is not an element of the group $G$. $ms$ is defined in standard way as the the sum of $m$ $s$'s. Please read some group theory basics again then raise questions.

Comment: In everything I have read $ab$ is written for $a \cdot b$. I have never seen $ab$ defined as the sum of $m$ $s$’s so I think my question is reasonable and it has nothing to do with my understanding of group theory basics.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdditiveGroup.html. Read the whole page carefully. You will find the definition of $m$-fold sum of group elements. See if you understand.

Comment: @AzamatBagatov If you're thinking of the group operation as multiplication, then that line would read $f(s^m) = m$. It's just common to write $m$th powers as multiplication by $m$ if you're calling the group operation $+$.